# How to do Inheritance Modeling in Relational Databases?

Tags: mysql, database, inheritance, data-modeling, class-table-inheritance

My question is regarding Inheritance modeling in Relational Database Systems. I have canonical data model and in that I have some fields related to pricing of product inheriting certain attributes from product table and I want to model this inheritance in MySQL relational database and so,

"How can we do Inheritance Modeling in Relational Databases ?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Martin Fowler discusses this extensively in his book Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture book. Get this book and look into:

1. [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

> [image: Blockquote]

2. [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)

> [image]

3. [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

> [image: Blockquote]

The Website should give you some idea. You might also want to read the section on [inheritance mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/inheritanceMappers.html). Each of the different approaches have their pros and cons so choose wisely.

Comment: This answer involves buying a book to be completely realized. Any chance you could add similar web resources?

Comment: While this answer points the OP in the right direction regarding Generalization/Specialization, it does not answer does now answer OP's question on how to model it in MySQL. Martin Fowler doesn't actually explain how to write SQL for developing these models.

Answer (score 8):

Look at these articles for some ideas:

[Mapping Objects to Relational Databases](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-mapping-to-rdb/)

[Inheritance in O/R Mapping](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/inheritance-mapping.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to look at some web articles instead of reading a book, you can find some good articles by Googling on:

```
Generalization Specialization Relational Modeling
```

The gen-spec pattern covers a lot of the same ground that inheritance does in OOP environments.

If you google on

```
Generalization Specialization Object Modeling
```

you'll get a whole new batch of articles, most of which mention inheritance explicitly.

There is a design technique that's summarized in the following tag [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) under the info tag.  This allows you to use subclass tables to "extend" a class table, if you'll allow a strange use of the word "extend".  There's some work involved, but it's worth it.

Comment: While this isn't really an answer in an idealized S.O. sense, I found it very useful.

Answer (score 5):

Relational databases don't deal with objects (and, thus, inheritance) - they deal with relationships. What you're really asking is how to map your object structure to your database - and the answer to that is "it depends on your ORM layer".

Take a look at [Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html) article for some details. If you tell us what software stack you're using, you'll likely get a more to-the-point answer.

Comment: This may sound pedantic but I don't think it's accurate to say that relational databases deals with relationships, but rather they are called such because they deal with relations as defined here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)

Comment: @Ralph: Wiki is an abscess; the confabulators have no certification.  Relational Databases deal with Entities and Relations, not objects.  Objects can be mapped easily if the RDb is truly Relational; and not if it is not.

Comment: You can have table inheritance without an ORM

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 6 of "Practical Issues in Database Management" is probably an interesting read for you.

As are all the other chapters, probably, but those don't relate directly to your question.