# Table design and class hierarchies

Tags: language-agnostic, database-design, orm, class-hierarchy

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this issue through either an example, or perhaps some suggested reading. **I'm wondering what is the best design approach for modeling tables after their class hierarchy equivalencies**. This can best be described through an example:

```
abstract class Card{
    private $_name = '';
    private $_text = '';
}

class MtgCard extends Card{
    private $_manaCost = '';
    private $_power = 0;
    private $_toughness = 0;
    private $_loyalty = 0;
}

class PokemonCard extends Card{
    private $_energyType = '';
    private $_hp = 0;
    private $_retreatCost = 0;
}
```

Now, when modeling tables to synchronize with this class hierarchy, I've gone with something very similar:

```
TABLE Card
  id            INT, AUTO_INCREMENT, PK
  name          VARCHAR(255)
  text          TEXT

TABLE MtgCard
  id            INT, AUTO_INCREMENT, PK
  card_id       INT, FK(card.id)
  manacost      VARCHAR(32)
  power         INT
  toughness     INT
  loyalty       INT

TABLE PokemonCard
  id            INT, AUTO_INCREMENT, PK
  card_id       INT, FK(card.id)
  hp            INT
  energytype    ENUM(...)
  retreatcost   INT
```

The problem I'm having is trying to figure out how to associate each `Card` record with the record containing it's details from the corresponding table. Specifically, how to determine what table I should be looking in.

Should I add a `VARCHAR` column to `Card` to hold the name of the associated table? That's the only resolution that my peers and I have come to, but it seems too "dirty". **Keeping the design extensible is the key here, allowing for the easy addition of new subclasses**.

If someone could provide an example or resources showing a clean way of mirroring class/table hierarchies, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at what (N)Hibernate does? It might give you some ideas about different possible approaches.

Comment: @Philipp: No, but I've seen it mentioned in other threads on this topic. I'll certainly investigate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google "generalization specialization relational modeling".  You'll find several excellent articles on the subject of how to model the gen-spec pattern using relational tables.  This same question has been asked many times in SO, with slightly different details.

The best of these articles will confirm your decision to have one table for generalized data and separate tables for specialized data.  The biggest difference will be the way they recommend using primary and foreign keys.  Basically, they recommend that specialized tables have a single column that does double duty.  It serves as the primary key to the specialized table, but it's also a foreign key that duplicates the PK of the generalized table.

This is a little complicated to maintain, but it's very sweet at join time.

Also keep in mind that DDL is required when a new class is added to the hierarchy.

Comment: can you provide an example or reference of a primary key in the specialized table in the fashion you describe?

Comment: @orange, good comment.  I'm going to have to look over the articles to see if one of them has a good illustration of the point.

Comment: Thanks **Walter Mitty**; There are some great resources on overcoming object-relational impedance mismatch, including another SO thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Fowler's website.  This is good stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Basically don't.

Forget about class hierarchies, storage models, and anything that is specific to your app and your particular app language.  Unless you want to use the RDb as a mere storage location for your files, a dependent slave.

If you want the power and flexibility (specifically extensibility) of the relational Database, then you need to model it independent of any app, and using RDb principles, not app language requirements.  Leave your app context behind for a while and design the database as a database.  Learn about them.  Normalise (eliminate all duplication).  Learn about the structures and rules, and implement them.  When you do that, your queries and your "mapping", will be effortless.  There will be no "impedance".  Use the correct datatypes and there will be no mismatch.

The structure you require is an ordinary subtype-supertype. Those are Relational Database terms that have been in existence for over 30 years in the RM, and over 23 years in Relational Database products.  No need to call them funny new names.  Wikipedia is not an academic reference.

Given your tables, which are quite correct as a starting point (you've Normalised automatically), you need:

- Rename Card.Id as Card.CardId
- Remove the ids for the subtypes, they are 100% redundant; the CardId is both the PK and the FK.
- Add a discriminator Card.CardType CHAR(1) or TINYINT.  This will identify which subtype to join with, when the CardType is not known.
- It appears you do not fully understand the concept of Foreign Keys, so that would be good to gear up on first.  It is implemented here in its simple, ordinary form:

```
    ALTER TABLE MtgCard
        ADD CONSTRAINT Card_MtgCard_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (CardId)
        REFERENCES Card(CardId)
```

- The relation between Card and MtgCard or PokemonCard is always 1::1.  The supertype is complete only when there is a Card plus { MtgCard | PokemonCard } with the same CardId.  In your case there can be only one subtype, easy to enforce with a simple CHECK constraint.

  - In [**other cases**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Swartz%20101111.pdf), more than one subtype is quite legal.
  - The subtypes there are *Person Is a Teacher* or *Person Is a Student*
- In Relational Databases there is no concept of joining "from" or "to" (or up/down or left/right), those notions are only there to assist us humans; you can start with any table/key you have, and go to any table you need.  The tables in-between are demanded only in the absence of Relational Identifiers (ie. where *additional* Surrogates, ID columns, are used as PKs *instead of* meaningful natural keys).

  - In the example, using your terms, you can *go* straight *from* Enrollment *to* Person (eg, to grab the LastName) or *to* Course (to grab the Name) without having to visit the intermediate tables; the relation lines are solid.
    .
- Now, class hierarchies ("Is" or "Is a") and anything else, are simple and effortless.

[**Quick Reference**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) to Standard Relational Database Diagrams.