# Relational database design tables with common base

Tags: database, relational

I have a lot trouble finding the best design solution for this situation. I have two tables with a common base. Currently I have designed it like this: I have an order table (the common base):

```
[order_table]
 order_id
 order_type
 company
 created
```

I have another table with reference to the order table:

```
[product_order]
 order_id fk
 product_id
 quantity
 price
```

I have second table with reference to the order table:

```
[special_order]
 order_id fk
 description
 price_estimate
 color
 size
```

Both tables share the same order_id which i like. I often have to do large queries on order_table using the information available in that table lets say 'company = 200'. But for each result I also need its data from product_order or special_order depending on which type it is. So the only optimal solution I see is to left joining the query with both tables on order_id and filter the information afterwards. The only other option I see is to add the common columns to each table, but then I would have a lot of reorganizing afterwards to get them in correct order.

Is there a better way to organize the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Inheritance Modeling in Relational Databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases)

Comment: Are `order -> product_order` and `order -> special_order` both one-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 0):

So those extra tables are extra attributes to a specific order-id (1:1)?

I'd consider adding all the fields to the common tables, or at least the fields from the most used sub-table.

If not appropriate, you may want to add "Type" to the common table and let a trigger manage insert/delete of related records to avoid the fuzz with orphans etc.

Use views with your left joins (wouldn't inner be better?) to fetch the different types.

Comment: yes they are 1-1. yeah adding all fields to the common table would solve the problem, but it is just not a nice design, because half would be missing these field and second half would be missing the other fields, but in practice it may be best solution :)

Comment: but thinking about it adding all fields to the common table would result in the same as just left joining the three tables in the query and correcting data afterwards, and with the correct indexes it will probably be just as fast.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of NULL values, and how relations work in a database. With very few exceptions (and yours isn't one) you should not have 1:1 relations in your database at all. It is less of a performance concern, but a design pattern. Doing two left joins when a single select would do adds complexity to your database without any benefit. Also, you need to go an extra mile to maintain the referential integrity. You really should consider a table redesign. Edit: I resurrected an old question for no appearant reason. Oh, my.