# Using database cyclic entity design

Tags: database, data-modeling

I'd like to store company data which has branch and each branch has different department. I have the following options:

1. Create Company, Branch and Department entity to store 3 different information.
2. create one entity which has the cyclic relationship and use company type to differentiate.
   Possible data structure: company (id, CompanyName, type, parent)
   possible data:

### **Company.**

> Id >CompanyName    >Type  >Parent
>
> 1  >Honda >HQ >NULL
>
> 2  >Honda US  >B >1
>
> 3  >Honda Japan   >B   >1
>
> 4  >Honda US HR   >D   >2
>
> 5 >Honda US Sales >D   >2

I am inclined to use option 2 as if there is a new requirement like Conglomerate as high level the option 2 will be able to resolve it without introducing new table.

Will this design make sense or it will cause the problem in the future?
Please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got two related, but separate questions to answer.

Firstly - [how do I store inheritance relationships in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases)? Company, department, and branch are all instances of "business unit" - if they are all mostly the same, you could use a single table, but if they are all rather different, a single table is often a bad design (see the other SO question for more context).

The second question is "how do I store hierarchical relationships in my inheritance model?". For consistency, I'd store this in the same model you chose for your inheritance solution; but it may make sense to have a separate "relationships" table. This would allow you to deal with unexpected relationships - for instance, a branch could be a joint venture between two departments.

Comment: Thank You @Neville for the answer. It addressed my doubt.