# Postgresql - create table with disjoint subclasses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm unsure how one can create a table on postgresql with disjoint subclasses. I have represented (a very simplified version of) my problem below in an ER diagram, showing the two subclasses and the attributes of each subclass.

[image]

For the columns common to all rows (id, common1, common2), it's clearly very simple (as shown in the code below).

```
create table Music (
    id          serial,
    common1 int not null, 
    common2 boolean not null, 

--<what to put here???>

);
```

However I'm not sure of the best way of considering the subclass issue. Does anyone know where to go from here?

Comment: What do layers, at1, lead, and strings and their values represent?

Comment: I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases) may help you.

Comment: @Schwern Columns of symphony are id, common1, common2, layers, and at1. Columns of concerto are id, common1, common2, lead and strings. I'm wondering if this can all be considered in a single table named Music.

Comment: @CarlosBazilio looked through this, but only contains references to books which I don't want to purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postgres table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) would work like so:

```
create table music (
    id serial primary key,
    common1 int not null, 
    common2 boolean not null
);

create table symphony (
    layers int not null,
    at1 text not null
) inherits(music);

create table concerto (
    lead text not null,
    strings integer not null
) inherits(music);
```

Consider if we have a row in each table.

```
insert into concerto (common1, common2, lead, strings)
  values (1, true, 'a', 5);
insert into symphony (common1, common2, layers, at1)
  values (2, false, 3, 'b');
insert into music (common1, common2)
  values (3, true);
```

They are all rows of music.

```
-- Fetches id, common1, and common2 from all rows.
select *
from music
```

If you only want to query rows in music specify `only music`.

```
-- Fetches id, common1, and common2 from only the one row in music.
select *
from only music
```

If you want to use symphony columns, you have to query symphony.

```
-- Fetches id, common1, common2, layers, at1 only from symphony
select *
from symphony
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc71f6514a18bb2672a4a251d904f206)

---

A more traditional structure would use join tables like so:

```
create table music (
    id serial primary key,
    common1 int not null, 
    common2 boolean not null
);

create table music_symphony (
    music_id integer references music(id),
    layers int not null,
    at1 text not null
);

create table music_concerto (
    music_id integer references music(id),
    lead text not null,
    strings integer not null
);

insert into music (id, common1, common2)
  values (1, 1, true);
insert into music_concerto(lead, strings)
  values ('a', 5);

insert into music (id, common1, common2)
  values (2, 2, false);
insert into music_symphony (music_id, layers, at1)
  values (2, 3, 'b');
  
insert into music (id, common1, common2)
  values (3, 3, true);

-- Fetch all symphonies
select *
from music m
join music_symphony ms on ms.music_id = m.id
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92a1c19a8ecbbb011ba77ffb9a399895)