# Subtypes and supertypes in my sql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-framework, mysql-workbench

I have the following diagram:
[image]

That I have to translate into conceptual model using mySQL workbench. But how can I do?
In workbench, while creating eer model, the is no option to define super types and subtypes. So how would you represent it?

[image: How would you continue?]

How to continue?

Answer (score 0):

Relations between supertypes and subtypes have nothing specific:

You can create a table Manager with SSN as foreign key and thus have a relation 0..1 between those two table

Comment: So I should create 3 different tables, PERSON, CLIENT and MANAGER, where PERSON is connected to CLIENT(and MANAGER) with 1:M non identifying relationship?

Comment: yes, if you really want to have PERSON table. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases) to have more info about other solutions

Comment: The problem is that in this way, if I enter a person with PK 03, for example, then I can add both a Manager and a customer with the same PK 03. Instead I would like that sql give me error if I try to add both customer and manager with the same PK. Persons's PK should be used just from A customer or A manager, not both

Comment: You can create a trigger to avoid such case: