# What is the best way to design the transactions table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Users table**

| ID | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | ETC... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 348 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Ads table**

| ID | USER_ID | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | ETC... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91 | 348 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Transactions table**

| COST | NUMBER_OF_DAYS | TRANSACTION_DATE | TYPE | AD_ID | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3000 | NULL | ... | 1 | NULL | 348 |
| -800 | 30 | ... | 2 | NULL | 348 |
| -50 | NULL | ... | 3 | 91 | 348 |
| -300 | 19 | ... | 4 | 91 | 348 |

**There are 4 types of transactions**

- 1 = When the user adds money to his wallet.
- 2 = When the user buys a gold membership.
- 3 = When the user reposts his ad. (The ad will appear again on the top of the list)
- 4 = When the user makes his ad a featured ad. (The ad will appear top of the non-featured ads)

I don't like designing the transactions table in this way because there are columns not required according to type value, Is there any better way to design the transactions table?

Comment: Question is likely to attract opinion based responses. Mine is I prefer to keep all transactions in 1 place and live with redundancy.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have a notifications table also with 28 types and the notifications table is designed like the transactions table, Do you think the design of my tables is good?

Comment: "Good" is by definition opinion based. How should we evaluate "good"? What are the characteristics of a "good" design in your case?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Everything is working well on the client side but I'm asking here because maybe there is a better way to design the table than the current way, I hate this design only because according to the type value some columns will be used and some will not. I think NoSQL will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of mapping inheritance relationships ("there are 4 types of transaction") to the relational database model. TL;DR: there are no elegant solutions - you have to choose the kind of inelegance you want. [There are 3 common approaches.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567935/how-to-do-inheritance-modeling-in-relational-databases)

Your design is an example of "single table inheritance". It's the simplest to work with - the other options involve adding tables to the design, with the need to join - but it requires columns that aren't always populated. It also pushes the validation of the object to the application layer - you can't create DDL to ensure that `AD_ID is not null` for entities of type 1 and 2.